# insert value into table from another table mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 db tables, one contains the order_id and customer_id who made the order,
and another table contains the order_id and product_ids for each order_id.

I want to add a column(customer_id) to the second table that brings customer id from the first table and add it to the second one according to the order_id.
I wrote this sql :

```
INSERT into order_producttest2(`customer_id`) SELECT `customer_id` FROM `order` WHERE `order`.`order_id`= order_producttest2.order_id
```

but I have the following error msg:
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1054 - Unknown column 'order_producttest2.order_id' in 'where clause'

although that there is a column order_id in order_producttest2 table

any help

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax:

```
INSERT into order_producttest2(`customer_id`) 
SELECT `order`.`customer_id` 
FROM `order` 
JOIN order_producttest2
  ON `order`.`order_id`= order_producttest2.order_id ;
```

Comment: I got #1364 - Field 'order_id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: @user2148116 So your entire idea is not valid. I think that you need to add column (ALTER TABLE + UPDATE) not to add rows.